# grep or awk? : Find similar substring and output in two fields

Tags: grep, output, field

I Have two files, I want to find the strings of file1 as substring in file2,
but want the output of the results (when matching) containing both strings in two fields divided by ':'
So that my output of matches has "**file1string:file2string**"

Example 
file 1

```
464697uifs4h44yy
48oo895i6iu8gg11
j4h5y7yu4g655h44
jyyuthvcxx22zerc
```

File 2

```
j4h5y7yu4g655h447ijj651cvpijgtkk
strxzdokui464697uifs4rdffgjfudjh
kjhbdfgfx1154m87gjgbgcsqubyu6u3k
gfhgysj4h5y7yu4g655h44jkhgfhhfhu
```

Desired Output

```
j4h5y7yu4g655h44:j4h5y7yu4g655h447ijj651cvpijgtkk
j4h5y7yu4g655h44:gfhgysj4h5y7yu4g655h44jkhgfhhfhu
```

**j4h5y7yu4g655h44:j4h5y7yu4g655h44**7ijj651cvpijgtkk
**j4h5y7yu4g655h44**:gfhgys**j4h5y7yu4g655h44**jkhgfhhfhu

I used :

```
fgrep -f file1 file2 >output
```

but this gives only results from file 2

Comment: define "comparison in two fields"

Comment: thanks for reply. I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.